# How to git init specific file or folder excluding all other files or folder in the same directory?

Tags: git, gitpython

I have a directory containing lots of files and folders ,
when I run `git init` after going inside it then it will init all files and folder in that folder, but I want to know if there is a `git` way of adding only specific files and folder to that `git init`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find the need operations described in https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

here is a few lines of code that might give you a picture of how to approach your need:

```py
import os
from git import Repo

gitPath="%s/.git" % path
if not os.path.isdir(gitPath):
  print("initializing git repository ...")
  repo=Repo.init(path)
  repo.index.add(...) # add you files and directories here as needed
else:
  repo=Repo(path)
```